# All the Data elements are not visible in tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop, bi-tool

I am using Tableau public 2021.3 and I have attached multiple CSV files as connections in the tableau. The problem that I am facing is that I am able to view that there are for example 20 rows in the given data table but the same 20 rows are not visible on the data source page and also on the sheets(where we can make charts ), some data rows are not visible they are deleted ???

for example, here we can see in the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbyrL.jpg that the customer's table has 38 rows in it but here https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHIcP.jpg  we can see that there are only 24 rows visible why is this happening ,i have not applied any filter on the table also.